# Data migration issue on live enviroment

Tags: database, oracle, migration, data-migration, downtime

I am planning to migrate data which resides in oracle database to a CMDB application database.

Since the database is not visible for end users/Developers of CMDB, we use API to import data into CMDB.

Currently my issues is , i cannot shutdown the oracle database while we do migration, means, oracle database will always insert data while i do migration through an ETL tool. So even though migration finish, again data will be filled in oracle database.

How can i get around this situation?without a down time? or is it never possible?

Comment: Not yet decided, but your advice is valuable

Answer (score 0):

To minimise downtime: assuming all tables have a primary key (which they should), record each tables' primary key value at point of migration, migrate the bulk of the data up to the recorded key values, then perform a second step with a small outage to pick up any further changes.

It might be further complicated if you have many new foreign keys being created. I would record all the primary key values in a serializable transaction to ensure a consistent view across all the data.

Your question is quite broad, so this answer is high level. Suggest you add more detail, if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice